# How to use forEach loop to automate querySelector for elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, foreach

I have an array with object that looks like this:

```
const boxes = [
  {jsName: '.js-box1', boxName: 'upperLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box2', boxName: 'upperCenter'},
  {jsName: '.js-box3', boxName: 'upperRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box4', boxName: 'centerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box5', boxName: 'centerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box6', boxName: 'centerRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box7', boxName: 'lowerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box8', boxName: 'lowerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box9', boxName: 'lowerRight'}
];
```

.jsName refers to the class name of some div boxes.

boxName is what the new name should be when selecting them with queryselector (explained below).

I want to use a forEach loop to querySelect each .js-box and give each the name of its associated boxName.

Writing that out manually looks like this:

```
const upperLeft = document.querySelector(`.js-box1`);
const upperCenter= document.querySelector(`.js-box2`);
const upperRight= document.querySelector(`.js-box3`);
const centerLeft= document.querySelector(`.js-box4`);
const centerMiddle= document.querySelector(`.js-box5`);
const centerRight= document.querySelector(`.js-box6`);
const lowerLeft= document.querySelector(`.js-box7`);
const lowerMiddle= document.querySelector(`.js-box8`);
const lowerRight= document.querySelector(`.js-box9`);
```

I tried to use a foreach loop to store each document.querySelector inside a const called element.boxname:

```
boxes.forEach( (element) => {
  const element.boxName = document.querySelector(`${element.jsName}`); 
}
)
```

This returns an error with: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'element' has already been declared`

Comment: So you want to set the text of those boxes to the value in `boxName` ?

Comment: No, I want to set the variable name to the boxName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is to create dynamic named variables.

For my answer, I created an empty object called elements. Then loop through your boxes array and add a dynamic key for each boxName set to the appropriate querySelector.

After the loop, you can just refer to them as
**elements["upperLeft"]**, **elements["upperCenter"]** etc

Although not an important change, I removed the template literals from the querySelector since they aren't needed. You have the full selector in jsName.

```js
const boxes = [
  {jsName: '.js-box1', boxName: 'upperLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box2', boxName: 'upperCenter'},
  {jsName: '.js-box3', boxName: 'upperRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box4', boxName: 'centerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box5', boxName: 'centerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box6', boxName: 'centerRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box7', boxName: 'lowerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box8', boxName: 'lowerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box9', boxName: 'lowerRight'}
];

let elements = {};

boxes.forEach((element) => {
  elements[element.boxName] = document.querySelector(element.jsName);
});

console.log("upperLeft",elements["upperLeft"])
```

```html
<div class="js-box1"></div>
<div class="js-box2"></div>
<div class="js-box3"></div>
<div class="js-box4"></div>
<div class="js-box5"></div>
<div class="js-box6"></div>
<div class="js-box7"></div>
<div class="js-box8"></div>
<div class="js-box9"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be instead of looping over all your elements and storing their DOM elements in an object variable, Why not use a simple function that returns you DOM element instantly:

```js
const boxes = [
  {jsName: '.js-box1', boxName: 'upperLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box2', boxName: 'upperCenter'},
  {jsName: '.js-box3', boxName: 'upperRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box4', boxName: 'centerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box5', boxName: 'centerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box6', boxName: 'centerRight'},
  {jsName: '.js-box7', boxName: 'lowerLeft'},
  {jsName: '.js-box8', boxName: 'lowerMiddle'},
  {jsName: '.js-box9', boxName: 'lowerRight'}
];

function getBox(name){
  let box = boxes.find(({boxName})=>boxName===name)
  return document.querySelector(box.jsName)
}

console.log("upperLeft",getBox("upperLeft"))
```

```html
<div class="js-box1"></div>
<div class="js-box2"></div>
<div class="js-box3"></div>
<div class="js-box4"></div>
<div class="js-box5"></div>
<div class="js-box6"></div>
<div class="js-box7"></div>
<div class="js-box8"></div>
<div class="js-box9"></div>
```